# Redirect all but certain requests to index

Tags: redirect

I have a defined in routes.php a regex that redirects all queries but api to my index template:

```
return array(
   '<url:(?!api).*>' => ['template' => 'index']
);
```

I'm trying to exclude robots.txt as well as Google Analytics which is `utm_source=analytics_test&utm_medium=referral` I've tried the following but it's not quite right:

```
return array(
   '<url:^(?!api|robots|utm_source)(.*)$>' => ['template' => 'index']
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will redirect all queries but urls containing: 
`api` or `robots` or `utm_source` strings

```
return array(
   '^(?!.*(api|robots|utm_source)).*$' => ['template' => 'index']
);
```